# Storing image file in server file system using Image URI

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, cordova, asp.net-web-api

I am getting URL from this Cordova Camera API and I am posting to WEBAPI. I tried with base64 but it increases the image size when I post it in server.

Please find my code below and suggest me how to save file to server.

```
  //WEB API//
  public  IHttpActionResult UpdateUserDetails(ImageModel model)
 {
try
{
    if (model.ImageBase64 != "")
    {
        var PicDataUrl = "";
        string ftpurl = "ftp://xxx.xxxxx.xxxx/";
        var username = "xxx";
        var password = "xxxxx";
        string UploadDirectory = "xxxx/xx";
        string FileName =model.ImageFileName;
        String uploadUrl = String.Format("{0}{1}/{2}", ftpurl, UploadDirectory,FileName);
        FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);
        req.Proxy = null;
        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        req.EnableSsl = false;
        req.UseBinary = true;
        req.UsePassive = true;

 // I am getting URI path like below and need to save this file in server

   model.ImageBase64 =  C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\services5.jpg

        byte[] data =Convert.FromBase64String(model.ImageBase64);
        req.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Close();
    }
}
}

 // I am getting URL from this Cordova Camera API and I am posting to WEBAPI

function onSuccessEdituserProfileGallery(imageData) {
console.log(imageData);
var smallImage
smallImage = document.getElementById('EdituserProfileImage');

smallImage.src = imageData;
customerImgData =smallImage.src;
return customerImgData;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

usually i do this:

Back End:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Upload/Image")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadImg()
        {
            try
            {
                #region VAR

                if (!Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Concat("~", Constant.Application.User_Cropped_Image_Directory)))) ;
                Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Concat("~", Constant.Application.User_Cropped_Image_Directory)));

                string mapPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Concat("~", Constant.Application.User_Cropped_Image_Directory));

                HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
                String fileName = "";

                #endregion VAR

                #region SPLIT

                // Get base64 string from POST
                var base64String = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                // SPLIT Content from unecessary data
                var split = base64String.Split(',');
                var strings = split[1].Split('-');

                #endregion SPLIT

                // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
                byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(strings[0]);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

                // Convert byte[] to Image
                ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
                if (!Directory.Exists(String.Concat(mapPath, fileName).ToLowerInvariant()))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(String.Concat(mapPath, fileName).ToLowerInvariant());

                fileName = GenericUtils.GetFileNameWithExt(image).ToLowerInvariant();

                //name = String.Concat("croppedImage_", fileName);
                image.Save(String.Concat(mapPath, fileName).ToLowerInvariant());



                return Ok(new { data = String.Concat(Constant.Application.User_Cropped_Image_Directory, fileName).ToLowerInvariant() } );
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogException(ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Ionic (js):

```
 $scope.takeFromCamera = function () {
             document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
                 var options = {
                     quality: 90,
                     destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                     sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                     allowEdit: true,
                     correctOrientation: true,
                     encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                     targetWidth: 600,
                     targetHeight: 600,
                     popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                     saveToPhotoAlbum: true
                 };

                 if ($cordovaCamera)

                     $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                         $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                         //Image in Base64 to send to server for web profile
                         // var imgRaw = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                         $upload.upload({
                             url: enviroment.apiUrl + 'api/Upload/Image',
                             fields: { 'base64String': $scope.imgURI },
                             file: $scope.imgURI
                         }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                             $scope.imageName = data.data;
                             $rootScope.$broadcast("update-img", { img: $scope.imageName });
                         });

                     }, function () {
                         $cordovaToast.show('Camera non Disponibile Si Prega di Riprovare piu tardi!', 'long', 'center');
                     });
             }, false);
         };
```

Comment: Thanks Federico. Your code and the code I am using is almost same. 
Problem is when I convert to base64, the file saved in server, size gets increased nearly 10 times the original size of the file.  Do you face the same thing